# Nesting promises for a parallel effect?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I've had to nest a promise within a promise, is this okay, or considered bad practise?

1. I've a class which has a method, `fetchArticles`, `fetchImages`, and `main`.

   - The `main` is the one which calls `fetchArticles` + `fetchImages`
   - `fetchArticles` runs a function from another file which returns a promise, but I'm also returning a promise on the `fetchArticles` class method itself, so when it's fetched the articles, it will go ahead and fetch the images.
   - `fetchImages` method is not promised but calls a promised function from another file.

I'm unsure if this is the best way to achieve a parralel effect?

```
main () {
    // Call the promised fetchArticles class method
    this.fetchArticles()
    .then ( () => this.fetchImages( () => {
         this.res.json(this.articles.data);
    }));
}


fetchArticles () {
    return new Promise ((fullfil, rej) => {
      // Calling a promised function which simply returns an array of articles
      fetchArticles (this.parametersForApiCall)
       .then ( (data) => {
        this.articles.data = data;
        this.articles.imageIds = [1,5,2,8,99,1000,22,44,55,120,241]; // Extract image IDS and save to class this
        fullfil();
      })
      .catch ( (err) => {
        console.log ("Something went wrong with api call", err);
        res.json({error: "Something went wrong", code: 1011});
        reject();
      });
    });
  }

fetchImages (cb) {
      // Calling a promised function which simply returns an array of images
    fetchImages (this.imageIds).then( (imgs) => {
      this.images = imgs;
      cb (); // Temp callback method
    }).catch ( (err) => {
      console.log (err, "error finding images in then")
    })
  }
}
```

Should I use something like async parallel? Note I've added a `callback` in the `fetchImages` method temporarily until I find a good solution for chaining promises.

Comment: nested promises are good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

1. you are creating an unnecessary promise in your `fetchArticles` function. You can return the result of the promisified fetchArticles directly.
2. Using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will let you fire off both items simultaneously. If your two methods aren't dependent on each other then this is a good way to go. I've updated the `main` function with that code.
3. Similarly, you can return the promise directly in your `fetchImages` function. Because this is also promisified, you no longer need the callback. I've removed it.

The resulting code

```
main () {
    // Call the promised fetchArticles and fetchImages class methods
    Promise.all([this.fetchArticles(), this.fetchImages()])
      .then(() => this.res.json(this.articles.data));
}


fetchArticles () {
  // Calling a promised function which simply returns an array of articles
  return fetchArticles (this.parametersForApiCall)
    .then ( (data) => {
      this.articles.data = data;
      this.articles.imageIds = [1,5,2,8,99,1000,22,44,55,120,241]; // Extract image IDS and save to class this
    })
    .catch ( (err) => {
      console.log ("Something went wrong with api call", err);
      res.json({error: "Something went wrong", code: 1011});
      reject();
    });
}

fetchImages () {
    // Calling a promised function which simply returns an array of images
    return fetchImages (this.imageIds).then( (imgs) => {
      this.images = imgs;
    }).catch ( (err) => {
      console.log (err, "error finding images in then")
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I've decided to accept yours as it's a lot more detailed!

Comment: Sure thing. Take a look at my explanatory edit for some other info that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a job for [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all).